# Batch reprojecting large number of MODIS files

Tags: coordinate-system, modis, modis-reprojection-tool

I am currently trying to reproject a large number (~14.000) of .hdf - files from MODIS Aqua/Terra from MODIS sinusoidal to something more popular (e.g. WGS1984). The files can be obtained from [LAADS](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/). The specific product I am interested in is "MOD04_3K - MODIS/Terra Aerosol 5-Min L2 Swath 3km" from Terra and "
MYD04_3K - MODIS/Aqua Aerosol 5-Min L2 Swath 3km" from Aqua.

So far, I have tried the following:

- reprojecting using ArcGIS (does not give desired results)
- [MODIS Reprojection Tool](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool) (does not support swath files)
- [MODIS Reprojection Tool Swath](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool_swath) (does not support the specific product)
- [HEG Tool](https://newsroom.gsfc.nasa.gov/sdptoolkit/HEG/HEGHome.html) (does work for one file, however, throws "Error: Null not found.", when trying to batch convert).

I also tried to manually batch process the files using [an online tutorial](https://newsroom.gsfc.nasa.gov/sdptoolkit/HEG/HEG_Batch_job_Help.htm), which left my with an empty output folder. I also tried the R packages [MODIStsp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MODIStsp/index.html), which does not seem to support the specific product I need.

Two example files can be found here: [CLICK](https://www.file-upload.net/download-13140028/indir.zip.html)

Does anyone have experience with that specific product or other ways to batch reproject .hdf-files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there are some files missing when installing HEG 2.14 that have to be added manually via a patch that can be downloaded [here](https://newsroom.gsfc.nasa.gov/sdptoolkit/HEG/HEGDownload.html).